# Angular Front-End call not calling the method in Spring Java Back-end and receiveing no logs

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring

I try to call the function from front to back, on the front side the logs are received successfully, but on the back side I receive nothing.

```
 updateLastConnection(): Observable<any> {

        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/update-last-connexion`;

        console.log('Update URL:', url); // Logging the URL

        console.log('Update called'); // Logging the function call

        return this.http.post(url, {}).pipe(

          tap(_ => console.log('Update request successful')), // Logging success

          catchError(error => {

            console.error('Update request error:', error); // Logging errors

            return throwError(error);

          })

        );

    }
```

Front logs:

Update URL: http://localhost:4200/api/users/update-last-connexion

Update called

Back-end side with no logs:

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/users/update-last-connexion", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> updateLastConnexion() {
        logger.info("Update last connection endpoint called.");
        String userId = SecurityControlle.getUserId();
        logger.info("User ID: {}", userId);
        try {
            this.userFacade.updateLastConnexion(this.userFacade.getCurrentUser(userId));
            logger.info("Last connection updated successfully.");
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error updating last connection: {}", e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }
```